# find all documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to find all documents in a DB using mongoose but I cant do it

I want to do it this way but I don't know what's wrong with it

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res){
    User.find({}, 'name', function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('user-list', {
                name : user.name
            });
            console.log('retrieved list of names' + user.name);
        }
    })
})
```

When I use `User.findOne({}, 'name', function(err, user){..` I get back the first doc which is what I would expect. Please explain why the code above is not allowing me to get all documents. I feel like I'm using it the right way as show in the  [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html)

Edit

thanks for help guys

i did like this:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res){
    User.find({}, 'name', function(err, users){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('user-list', {
                name : users.map(function(doc){
                    return doc.name + "<br>"
                })
            });
            console.log('retrieved list of names' + users.name);
        }
    })
})
```

can some one please help me with getting each name on a new line the `"<br>"` shows up on the page but it doesn't make a new line `"<br>,Joe<br>,mike<br>"`

Jade:
    extend layout

```
block content

    p list of users #{name}
```

Comment: `user` in your callback would be better named `users` because it's an array of all user docs in the collection.

Comment: BTW, the docs you linked to are for the old 2.7 version of Mongoose.  The current docs are at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that the naming could be better I was trying to get this  small thing up and running. can you help me with this? in the docs they have find({field : value}). I don't need a specific field.

Comment: user won't have a `name` in your callback because it is an array.

Comment: In your code, `user` is an array but you're accessing it like it's a single object (`user.name` won't work).

Comment: @JohnnyHK that's why it works with findOne, bec findOne t returns a single object. but `find()` returns an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res){
    User.find({}, 'name', function(err, users){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.render('user-list', users);
            console.log('retrieved list of names', users.length, users[0].name);
        }
    })
});
```

As said in the comments, `find` can find many objects, so it returns an array as contrasted with `findOne` that returns a single object. Adjust for that as above and you should be back on track.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get(`/users`, async (req,res)=>{
  try{
    const users = await User.find({}).exec()
    users && res.render('user-list',users)
  }catch(error){
   res.status(500).json({error})
  } 
})

//OR

app.get(`/users`, async (req,res)=>{
  try{
    const users = await User.find({}).exec()
    const list = new Array()
    for(let row of users){
      list.push(`${users.name}<br>`)
    }
    list ? res.status(200).send(list) : res.status(200).json({message: 'Users list is empty'}) 
  }catch(error){
   res.status(500).json({error})
  } 
})
```

In second example you send to client a text line!!!